# Is saving a terminal Vim split session possible?

Tags: terminal

I'm new to Vim I only know how to navigate and save sessions with `:mksession` so far but I'm unsure of how I could save my splits this is what my settup looks like.

https://imgur.com/a/2BGkbSP

One side would be Vim the other would be the regular terminal I open Vim within a terminal, I tried looking for help on youtube but all videos are showing a application called "tmux" and when I went to check if this application was what allowed me to split my terminal I couldn't find any thing on my computer about it.

I'm on Lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) LXQT version 0.17.0

Comment: You could open the terminal _inside_ Vim. See [`:terminal`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html?#%3Aterminal)

Comment: There is so much hided in the screen shot that it is hard to understand. Could you provide an alternative version?

Comment: Could you also tell us which terminal you are using?

Comment: @muru I considered this but I love the fact that I can slide my mouse back and forth to change the  panel sizes.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I just covered up my username I'm using the standard Lubuntu terminal I right clicked my mouse scrolled down to the "split terminal vertically" option and then opened up Vim. Still cannot figure a way to save this layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by running a terminal inside Vim/Neovim with the `:terminal` command, as muru recommended. Both will remember your terminal splits by default when running `:mksession`. Neovim will allow you to resize the splits with your mouse by default, but if you are using Vim you can enable the feature with `set mouse=nvi`

Comment: Neovim seems like a good choice for me but I will stick with Vim for now thank you!

Comment: Or `:set mouse=a`